# keypress event in jquery doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a page where i search wikipedia articles. I want that the page search when i click the button search ,or when i press enter key inside the input form. The problem is that the enter key only works if i click first the button search.Why?

Page:http://codepen.io/Juan1417/pen/XNJeWd

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#searchTerm").keypress(function(e){

        if(e.which==13) $("#search").click();

      });  

      $("#search").click(function(){

        var searchTerm=$("#searchTerm").val();

        var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+searchTerm+"&format=json&callback=?";

        $.ajax({

          type:"GET",
          url:url,
          async:false,
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(data){

           for(var i=0;i<data[1].length;i++){

             $("#output").prepend("<li><a href="+data[3][i]+" target='_blank'>"+data[1][i]+"</a><br><span>"+data[3][i]+"</span><br>"+data[2][i]+"</p></li>");

           } 

          },

          error:function(errorMessage){

            alert(errorMessage);

          }

        });

      });

   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you aren't stopping the function to run after the enter (so the form is submitted).

```
if(e.which==13) {
  $("#search").click();
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: What does stopPropagation do?

Comment: `stopPropagation` prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

You should use `preventDefault`instead. My mistake there, sorry, I updated the answer. 
`preventDefault` cancels the event if it is cancelable, without stopping further propagation of the event. 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: notice that the `return false` is the one that really does the job in most old browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=preventDefault